# How to bypass password prompt with vnc connection from terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

Previously, screen sharing to Catalina (10.15.7) from Big Sur (11.1) using terminal:

`open vnc://[user]:[password]@[host].local`

would open a screen sharing session without having to enter a password.

After the Big Sur 11.2 upgrade, Catalina now displays the login screen and asks for the password.

How can I correctly pass the password to the screen sharing session and bypass the login screen?

Comment: Have you considered setting up relevant SSH keys?  (Create a suitable key pair, append the public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote machine, and save the private key as e.g. ~/.ssh/id_rsa on the local machine.)  Then you won't need to specify a password.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that too but couldn't figure out how to properly pass credentials into VNC either.

[The docs for screen sharing](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-the-screen-of-another-mac-mh14066/mac) say that if both machines are signed into the same iCloud account, then a screen sharing session will begin. Otherwise a username password prompt is displayed. I didn't see much difference between the Catalina and the Big Sur versions of the page unfortunately.

If you want a work around, I hacked together some Apple Script that will open up the screen sharing app, fill in hostname, username/password, then re-enter the password on the remote machine and press enter:

```
tell application "Screen Sharing"
    activate # start Screen Sharing if not running yet
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 51 using {command down} # Delete whatever is in the textbox
        keystroke "192.168.1.1" # host you want to connect to
        key code 36 # press enter
        delay 1 # wait a moment for the next screen to appear
        keystroke "username" # username
        keystroke tab
        keystroke "hunter2" # password
        key code 36 # press enter
        delay 2 # wait to connect to the target machine
        key code 51 using {command down} # delete anything in the textbox
        keystroke "hunter2" # typing the password on the remote machines textbox
        key code 36 # hitting enter to log in
    end tell
end tell
```

To use throw the above code into a file called `file.scpt` and run it via `osascript file.scpt`. You need to give the Terminal app the Accessibility permission within the Security & Privacy section of the Settings app.